# Remove Duplicates, concatenated, from the top

Tags: vba

I have coded following macro, it is working when I save the values to immediate window, but don't know how to populate the values, delimited with "," into one cell. Basically I look for "Active" in a column, and if found, go 4 cells to the left and take the info from there...
 Could you help please?

```
Dim Active() As Variant
Dim i
ReDim Active(Range("G9:G24").Cells.Count)
For Each Zelle In Range("G9:G24")
If InStr(1, Zelle, "Active") <> 0 Then
Active(i) = Zelle.Offset(0, -4)
End If
i = i + 1
Next Zelle

 For i = LBound(Active) To UBound(Active)
 If Trim(Active(i)) <> "" Then
   Debug.Print Active(i)
   End If
  Next i
  End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to look into the Join function.

Comment: @RichHolton The Join function is natural, but the `Trim(Active(i)) <> ""` suggests that it might have empty fields which would have to be fixed after the join.

Comment: @JohnColeman Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can greatly shorten your code by looping through wanted range cells corresponding to not-blank cells only in column C

```
    Dim Zelle As Range
    Dim resultStrng As String

    For Each Zelle In Range("G9:G24").Offset(,-4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through not blank cell in range 4 columns to the left of G9:G24
        If InStr(1, Zelle.Offset(, 4), "Active") <> 0 And Trim(Zelle) <> "" And Instr(resultStrng, Trim(Zelle)) =0 Then resultStrng = resultStrng & Trim(Zelle) & "," '<--| update your result string whenever current cell has a character and its 4 columns to the right offset cell meets the "Active" criteria
    Next Zelle
    If resultStrng <> "" Then resultStrng = Left(resultStrng, Len(resultStrng) - 1) '<-- remove the last comma from 'resultStrng'
```

Comment: the code is working, now I am trying to add only unique values from the Array. Trying with another For To Loop, but cannot look through this...Any idea?

Comment: See edited code. If it solves your question you may want to mark answer as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following

```
Dim s As String
```

Then rewrite the loop like this:

```
For i = LBound(Active) To UBound(Active)
    If Trim(Active(i)) <> "" Then
        s = s & IIf(Len(s)>0, ",", "") & trim(Active(i))
      End If
Next i
```

Then you can assign `s` to a cell.